# Structure conventions in editor programs

Tags: java, structure, conventions

I'm writting an editor program. Like any good editor, it should have opening, saving and all the similar functions that go with it (usually found under the "File" menu in editor programs). However, I'm not sure how to write the code to be both functional and well structured.

Since what I'm talking about is major part of so many programs, I'm sure that some kind of standardized way of writing such code exists.

Can you point me to somewhere where I could find informations about that? I'm sure there must be books that deal with this matter, I just don't know what keywords to google to get viable resutls...

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

What have I tried so far?

Various combinations of Filechoosers and dialogs with boolean and String markers, always failing in the end, either due to code becoming chaos or getting lost in it's structure and failing to unify my markers.

I could put in some effort and make a working code, but since this is such a widespread problem I'm sure it's been done before, and what is most important, it has been done far better than I could ever do it. It's not that I'm lazy, I just want it to be done as best as possible.

I'm also not asking for the best source or book, but **a** source or **a** book. So I'm not encouraging a disscusion by asking for the best suggestion, I just want any suggestion I can get.

Comment: In Windows, there are system APIs to do that. They open that standard Open / Save window you see in most softwares that look pretty much the same in all of them. But since you are using Java, I'm not sure if there is a standard way.